# Можно ли найти по тексту id родителя?

Tags: php, dom, search

Делаю поиск на сайт, и мне нужно по тексту найти id родителя, как это можно сделать?

```
 <div id="a">
  <p>модуль</p>
 </div>

$a = file_get_contents("moduli.php");
$a = preg_split("~\\n(?=\\s+)~",$a);
$slovo = 'модуль';
foreach(preg_grep("~$slovo~ui",$a) as $v){
echo $v;
```

Или каким еще образом можно реализовать поиск карточки товара по слову введенному в поисковую сроку?

(бд не используется, вся инфа хранится в файлах, требование заказчика)

Comment: какой-то неадекватный заказчик у вас. в лююбом случае, имхо стоило бы написать какой нить индексатор, который при необходимости запускать при обновлении этих файлов. каждый раз читать файловую систему и парсить регулярками сомнительное предприятие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы Вам советовал воспользоваться библиотекой [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)

С помощью этой библиотеки, код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$html = file_get_html("<div id="a"> <p>модуль</p> </div>");
foreach ($html->find("модуль") as $result) {
    $id = $result->parent()->getAttribute("id");
}
```

И да, она ещё умеет парсить не валидный HTML.